# Find CSV cell enclosure

Tags: php, file, class, csv, quotes

I'm currently working on a CSV handling class that maily uses PHP's [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/fgetcsv) function.

I'd like to be able to detect the CSV file's delimiter and enclosure character.

Now I'm just trying to figure out how to find the cell enclosure, knowing that I've got some hell of a file to parse :

```
## *CSV File* ##
,,,foo,bar,,cats are
dead,lorem ipsum,csv,"this cell's enclosure is set",,
```

Anyway I can't figure out a good algorithm, for now I only thought of bruteforcing everything (reading the file with different enclosures and checking the output)...

Answer (score 2):

You can try all known combinations and then check if the outcome is valid:

- All lines have the same number of values

If this is possible with no enclosure you should prefer no enclosure.

Comment: In my case I have to read automatically generated CSV files from a database that can go to more than a thousand lines, so brute force is pretty slow.

Comment: Well you can start and if you run into the problem that it mismatches at row X, you then restart. Start with "no enclosure" to prefer it, then the combination you think is second most common etc. - you might even not need to restart for the non-enclosure mismatch but just start iterating over alternatives on first mismatch.

Comment: @Jean-MarieComets It might help speed up the process further to use something like [this](http://codepad.viper-7.com/vLXDVn) to identify possible candidates for the enclosure as soon as you know you need to find one (i.e. when no enclosure produces an invalid line). That is by no means perfect and I'm certain there are edge cases where it will go wrong, but it will get an array of possible candidates and the number of times they occur. It assumes enclosures will not be perl word characters and not `\r` or `\n` - it means your enclosures must match `[^a-zA-Z_\r\n]` and cannot be the delimiter.

Comment: Very elegant solution, I didn't think of using RegExps, I'll try and work that solution out.